# Use Office.js Access token as Authorization to back end

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in that consists of a React front-end and a dotnet core back-end service. I retrieve an an access token using the Office.js lib.

```js
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, async (result:Office.AsyncResult<string>) => {

});
```

The access token is sent to the back-end service and used to retrieve Graph access and refresh tokens.

My question, should I also be using the Office.js access token as an Authorization header in requests from the add-in front-end to the back-end? Would it provide any additional level of security or can I discard it once I've retrieved the Graph tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you're getting back is only usable with Microsoft Graph, and only for that user's mailbox. If you decode the token using https://jwt.ms you can see exactly which scopes are assigned (it's very limited).

If you want to leverage the user's identity for your own backend, there are a couple of options.

- [Authenticate a user with an SSO token in an Outlook add-in (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token)
- [Authenticate a user with an identity token for Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token)

There is an overview of authentication available at [Authentication options in Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authentication).